# "How rude are you" vs. "How rude you are"

Tags: questions, word-order, subject-auxiliary-inversion

I want to know about this two sentence whether both is correct or wrong.
If both is correct then where can I use this sentence?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! "How rude you are!": an exclamation. "How rude are you?": a question. Both sentences are correct, if used in appropriate circumstances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first statement is asking a question, "how rude are you?". This is a bit non-sensical as generally the person asking decides how rude the other person is, not the other way around.

The second sentence is correct, although it sounds a bit antiquated. Someone might say "How rude you are", meaning that "you are rude" or possibly even very rude. A better example would be someone saying "How tall you are" - expressing surprise and possibly delight that someone is taller than might be expected (a child, for instance).

A simple declarative sentence would be "you are rude".

Comment: The one time we might hear "How rude are you?" is when it's asked as a rhetorical question. In that circumstance, though, a native might ask instead, "How rude can you be?" The corresponding exclamation might be, "I can't believe how rude you are!"

Answer (score 2):

1. "How rude you are!": an exclamation, equal in meaning to "You are so rude!"
2. "How rude are you?": a question, meaning "What is the extent of your rudeness?"

Both sentences are correct, provided they are used in appropriate circumstances.

Example from Google Books:

> Gregory, how rude you are to give Mr. Lorraine all this trouble! But you never were famous for good manners.

---

Grammar: the question sentence uses the [subject-auxiliary inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion): the auxiliary verb "are" stands before the subject pronoun "you".